# How to extend intrinsic element with also overriding field type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have custom component `Button` I want to be able pass to it `value` field `ReactElement`.
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEBXGGCagBRzADOcJAA861ACZCA8iGAwAPACkAygA0AdAElaUGgOBoAogBskIJLQEBtfACMOXavgC6AGgIA3FCbZJ8AHzkAN7kAJD0OFAA-ABccAIwetQA5hRh3r5IcYjEMBrsnNwAEgAqALIAMgCCnHoOdAIKZVWFTqbmljABtpl+rnAAPrno+cijHRa0FAC+lKKQsHASSIxsJlhs1BjA3KyO3AAUwZHQHhoXYPwCM3Dxbdx8EIIAlCHhRDBsUNRwh+FhBQNJxwYIXDRXZ43IJhWEKCTATwBYKQwQaPpIGYKAD0CKRAJxwO4MLeMyAA)

```js
interface ButtonProps extends Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"], "value">
{
    error?: string;
    value?: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["value"] | React.ReactElement;
}

export default function Button({error, ...props} : ButtonProps)
{
    return (
        <button {...props}>
            <div>{props.value}</div>
        </button>
    )
}
```

I get error:

> Type '{ children: Element; value?: string | number | readonly string[] | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined; ref?: LegacyRef<...> | undefined; ... 274 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'.
> Type '{ children: Element; value?: string | number | readonly string[] | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined; ref?: LegacyRef<...> | undefined; ... 274 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
> Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | number | readonly string[] | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
> Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.

I know what cause the error. Returned `<button>` has incompatible `value` field type. How to solve it, without creating new field e.g. `content : React.ReactElement` (I want to `value` stay)?